# AngularJS: combine predefined localizable date format with a static format

Tags: angularjs

I would like to combine a predefined localizable date format with a static date format in AngularJS, something like this:

```
<select ng-options="i as (i | date : 'shortDate, EEE') for i in dates"></select>
```

The result should be:

```
EN: 10/25/2010, Sat
DE: 25.10.2010, Sa.
...
```

How can I achieve this in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
<select ng-options="i as ((i | date: 'shortDate') + (i | date: ', EEE')) for i in dates"></select>
```